# PHP Artisan Comand not working in Nginx with php-fpm on CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, centos7, laravel-artisan

Just finished setting up a LEMP (Linux, Nginx, MySQL and PHP) environment in a CentOS server. And after uploading a Laravel app everything seemd to be working correctly.

I needed to execute a php artisan command via SSH, and when i did i noticed that the command wasn't being executed correctly.
When i execute an artisan command in the application's folder i get the following message:

```
> php artisan
Usage: php [-n] [-e] [-h] [-i] [-m] [-v] [-t] [-p <prefix>] [-g <pid>] [-c <file>] [-d foo[=bar]] [-y <file>] [-D] [-F [-O]] 
(...)
```

I have php installed correctly and the app is running normally:

```
> php -v
PHP 7.1.8 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Aug  9 2017 13:21:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

What can be the issue?

**UPDATE: As @Devon suggested, i was not using the php-cli. So in order to solve my issue i installed php-cli in the server and everything is working as expected.**

Comment: Your php is pointing to a cgi binary instead of a cli binary.  Find the cli binary instead.

Comment: Thanks @Devon that was the problem. I didn't have installed the php-cli. It's working now :)